# How to create a generic function which depends on the parameter data type can infer right props

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics, react-tsx, union-types

I have some master/static data using which I can derive the various properties in a Entity by using the Ids and get name from the master data. To derive this I wan to create a generic function which depending on the which type of lookup data i am passing to the function it will use its properties to extract data.

But because my implementation is creating a union of Lookups data I'm getting the following errors.

```
type LookUpDataTypeA = {
  calenderId: number;
  calender: string;
  desc: string;
};

type LookUpDataTypeB = {
  timeZoneId: number;
  timeZoneValue: string;
  desc: string;
};

type Entity = {
  id: number;
  isActive: boolean;
  timeZoneId: number;
  timeZone?: string;
  calender?: string;
  calenderId: number;
};

const createEntity = (
  id = 1,
  isActive = true,
  timeZoneId = 10,
  calenderId = 14
): Entity => ({
  id,
  isActive,
  timeZoneId,
  calenderId,
});

const someEntities: Entity = [
  createEntity(), 
  createEntity(2, false, 12, 15)
];


const getNamebyId = (data:Entity, lookUpData:(LookUpDataTypeA | LookUpDataTypeB)[]) {
   return lookUpData.find(item => item.calenderId === data.calenderId).calender
}

// Errors:

// Property 'calenderId' does not exist on type 'LookUpDataTypeA | LookUpDataTypeB'.
//   Property 'calenderId' does not exist on type 'LookUpDataTypeB'.

// Property 'calender' does not exist on type 'LookUpDataTypeA | LookUpDataTypeB'.
//   Property 'calender' does not exist on type 'LookUpDataTypeB'.
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WkEx0N) work for you? If yes, I will write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! For the sake of asking a question I have added only two types of lookups but I have many such lookups with different types. Your approach may solve the problem here but what if I have many lookup types i had to do lot of logic and not extendable in case new lookups added in the system. I may have to make changes in future to the code.

Comment: Can you add a common field to `LookUpDataTypeA` and `LookUpDataTypeB` in that case? Something like: `LookUpDataTypeA.__type: 'a'` and `LookUpDataTypeB.__type:'b'`? This way, you will have better scalability. If you can add those I will suggest another approach

Comment: Though I have no control on the server side data these are legacy APIs but I may add when I get the data from server on client side.

Comment: Will something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND8xVN) work then?

Comment: how it will scale?

Comment: You will check only the type to determine if it is the entity that you are looking for instead of all fields that are needed to use

Comment: May be if you can explain it in playground or answer here how i will manage in case of I have 10-15 different types of LookUps. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean many types will have `calenderId` and `calender`? Or will they have many other things?

Comment: In this scenario it is best to create class and create entity would be be either instance of ClassA or ClassB rather than typeA or typeB you can use instance of to separate them out. You could also use a common type like entity which has all your props rather than union use that Entity type of Array

Comment: If there's some use case you care about, please [edit] your question to show it.  So if you're worried about scalability, put more LookUps in your example (Maybe 4-5 instead of 10-15).